# how to clear EditText set Error when a radio button is checked?

Tags: android, radio-button, textwatcher

I have four radio buttons in one group and four EditTexts.
I set EditText error when user enters zero value.
my problem is when user  selects for example radio button1 and enters 0 the error for edit text1 is shown BUT when user selects radio button2 the edit text1 error is not displayed!
how can I solve it> (I think TextWatcher can help me but I dont know how?)

Comment: Could you update your question and write some code to help you?